# execute a trigger when I create a table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl-trigger

I would like to know if a trigger on a system table of PostgreSQL can be executed when I create a table

I need to add 2 functions on each table of my database and I would like to do it dynamically

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

This can be done with an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_create_table_func()
RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    -- your code here
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER
on_create_table ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_create_table_func();
```

Note that there is no way to directly execute any query on the newly created table, or even get its name.
I don't know what you mean by "add 2 functions on each table" since functions don't belong to a specific table, but if you need to perform an operation specific for the new tables, this might not be for you.

Answer (score 16):

it has been implemented since version 9.3
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "DDL Triggers". They're not implemented in PostgreSQL. Neither you can add triggers to system tables. Look at this forum entry:

[Adding ddl audit trigger](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Adding-ddl-audit-trigger-td3358791.html)

Comment: @JotaBe deadlink

Comment: There are event triggers now.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/event-triggers.html