# Convert hypertable to regular postgres table

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, timescaledb

quite new to timescaledb and I'm struggling with a migration script. I'm trying to create migrations for a flask application with SQLAlchemy.

Let's say I created a table (as in timescaledb docs) like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE conditions (
  time        TIMESTAMPTZ       NOT NULL,
  location    TEXT              NOT NULL,
  temperature DOUBLE PRECISION  NULL,
  humidity    DOUBLE PRECISION  NULL
);
```

To add the hypertable, my upgrade migration script should do:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time');
```

What should the downgrade part look like ?
From [timescaledb docs](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/hypertables#drop), they suggest:

```
DROP table conditions;
```

But I don't want the whole table to be dropped, only the "hypertable" part if that makes sense. Maybe this is silly and pointless, I want to provide a way out of timescaledb via our migrations. I've already read this SO question: [Creating Hypertables through SQL Alchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862609/creating-hypertables-through-sql-alchemy) where no specific support seems provided for SQLAlchemy and they suggest triggers to create hypertables instead of a specific migration.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to migrate and drop.  A hypertable is not just some additional information we stick on top of an underlying table, it's a different partitioning/organization of the data.

So in the above command, when you immediately call `create_hypertable` after creating the table -- you don't yet have any data in the table, so we're just changing around schema definitions and such.  But if you call `create_hypertable` on a table that *already* has data (with the explicit `migrate_data` argument [1] to the `create_hypertable` command), we need to migrate data (which involves copying it from your existing table to the new internal chunks/tables we create.

Hence, "migrating it back" to a standard table would again involve moving the data around inside the hypertable, so it's really akin to just creating a new standard table, copying the data from the hypertable to the standard table, then deleting the hypertable.

[1] https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/

Answer (score 14):

As Mike says hypertables are an entirely different storage mechanism which means you cannot simply **turn them off**. Instead like when you convert a table with data to a hypertable you need to migrate a table out of a hyper table.

```sql
-- if you already have data in a table, you need to migrate that data
SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time',  migrate_data => true);
```

You could use any of the answers from here to copy data https://stackoverflow.com/a/31284533/897414 but here's what I'd do as part of a migration downgrade.

```sql
CREATE TABLE pg_conditions (LIKE conditions INCLUDING ALL); -- duplicate table structure
INSERT INTO pg_conditions (SELECT * FROM conditions); -- copy all data
DROP TABLE conditions; -- drops hypertable
ALTER TABLE pg_conditions RENAME TO conditions; -- conditions is now a regular postgres table again
```

Comment: Thanks for the late but precise answer !