# Postgres: Force to have a column in schema

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is it possible to intercept a `CREATE table` statement and ensure that a given column `column1` is present or return an exception?

Does anyone have any example?

Comment: My first guess was: Use Event Triggers - but this does not seem to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839746/execute-a-trigger-when-i-create-a-table

Comment: @madflow, what does not work is adding a trigger to a system table as the OP wanted to do in the link you show.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was referring to "Note that there is no way to directly execute any query on the newly created table, or even get its name. " (Quote from the Link). Maybe am mistaken then, and OP can get the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` event trigger fires after a table is created. You can get the OID of the created table and search for its columns in the system catalog `pg_attribute`. Example:

```sql
create or replace function create_table_event() 
returns event_trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare 
    r record;
begin
    for r in 
        select * 
        from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() 
        where command_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
    loop
        if not exists(
            select from pg_attribute
            where attrelid = r.objid
            and attname = 'column1') 
        then
            raise exception 'cannot create table %; table must have "column1" column', r.object_identity;
        end if;
    end loop;
end
$$;

create event trigger create_table_event
    on ddl_command_end when tag in ('CREATE TABLE')
    execute procedure create_table_event();
```

Read more in the documentation:

- [Overview of Event Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html)
- [Event Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html)
- [CREATE EVENT TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html)